# create zip on server and send to user using NODE JS

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I use third party API which give me multiple Images.

1) **first  I need to Download those Images on server and make ZIP of those all images.(Third party API provide Images URL's)**

2)**After creating Zip successfully user will be download that ZIP on its local system.**

i need to perform this task using nodejs or its NPM library's

please give me some  batter way for perform this

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hopping you have already saved the file on your server. Please check - http://programmerblog.net/zip-or-unzip-files-using-nodejs-tutorial/ for further steps

Answer (score 0):

```
import cmd from 'node-command-line'
import zipFolder from 'zip-folder'
import Download from 'image-downloader'
```

First of all create a direactory or folder to convert that into zip

```
const zipName = `zipFolderName`
//Folder name which become zip
cmd.run(`mkdir -p ${__dirname}/../public/`)          
//Create public direactory in server(backend)
cmd.run(`chmod -R 777 ${__dirname}/../public/`)
//Give persmission on public folder
cmd.run(`mkdir -p ${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}/`)
cmd.run(`mkdir -p ${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}/${zipName}/`)
```

Download all Image or file using url and store

```
const promiseArr = []
const url = decodeURI('path_of_url') //Decode url 
const fileName = url.replace(/.*\//g, '') //extract filename from url
const options = {
    url: urls[i],
    dest: `${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}/${zipName}/${fileName}`
    //Path of your zip file
}
Download.image(options)
        .then((filename) => {
            promiseArr.push(filename) //If we want to return promise
        })
```

sjkhderhkjwe

```
  zipFolder(`${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}/`, //path of folder
           `${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}.zip`, //where zip made
         async (err) => {
            if (err) {
                thorw new Error(err)
            } else {

                const urls = `${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}.zip`
                //const zipUrl = await uploadZipToAWS(zipName, urls)
                // Upload zip or move zip to front End 
                cmd.run(`rm -rf ${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}/`)
                //Remove this zip from server
                cmd.run(`rm -rf ${__dirname}/../public/${zipName}.zip`)
                //Remove this zip from server
               //Return back url
            }
        })
```

Please take care of Path(__dirname).
Install modules on server side. And Manage code based on your requirement.

Send back url(Path) of zip at front end and access or make it downloadable on browser.